# Error while updating Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04, 14.10

I'm trying to update Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 (actually, I want to have 15.04 but as I understood I can't do it directly).

So, I'm doing `update-manager -d` (without `-d` it suggests me to update to 15.04, what does not work), and I get this error:

```
WARNING:root:file 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' missing
```

and the upgrading process stops.

How should I fight this, and how can I update to 14.10 (or even to 15.04) from 14.04?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` first.

Comment: @Zacharee1: To properly upgrade, you really should be running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: There should be a way of directly upgrading, I saw it as an option added to the updates program in its changelog.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I meant to just get rid of the error; maybe some packages needed to be updated first.

Comment: @Zacharee1: That may be the case, however it is also possible that the packages needed will be held back by your command, so mine may be better.

Comment: @Zacharee1 done several times

Comment: @ParanoidPanda it runs and finishes without any errors or warnings. Though looks like it has nothing to do with  upgrading Ubuntu itself, only packages.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda and if I choose to upgrade it directly, I see

    `Could not calculate the upgrade
    An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.`

Comment: @Shtirlits: Why do you want to upgrade?  14.04.3 has still support until August 2016, whereas **14.10 is out of support right now** and 15.04 will run out of support at the end of the year...

Comment: As of 28 Jan 2016, I own a Dell laptop - with 14.04 LTS. Ffirst thing I did was try updating it to the latest version (15.10) . I had the same problems listed, and will be following the steps mentioned for upgrading an unsupported release. Thanks!

Comment: Any solution discovered?

Comment: The problem was solved in other way - I created bootable USB driver with 15.10 on it, rebooted and chose the 'Upgrade' option